# Django: View with conditional login_required

Tags: django, django-views, django-urls

Given the view, `latest_objs`, I wanted the view to require login conditionally if there is a parameter in the URL.

The goal:

1. If the URL passed is `latest-objs`, then return the non-authentication view with `objs` not related to any specific users.
2. If the URL passed is `latest-objs/mine`, I want to require login if the user isn't authenticated, as that version of the view is supposed to return `objs` related to the authenticated user.

Questions:

1. Is the right way to do this to check `request.GET.get('some-param')?`
2. How would I define these two scenarios in my `urls.py` file? Current I have this:

   ```
   url(r'latest-objs', views.latest_objs, name='latest_objs'),
   ```

A little off-topic: I'm wondering if it's worth bothering with this, or simply creating two different views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use `request.GET` when your URL has a querystring, e.g. `/latest-objs?owner=me`.

For a URL `/latest-objs/mine`, you have to modify your URL pattern, or add a new one. I prefer to add a new URL pattern because I think it's more readable. You can either use a new view,

```
url(r'latest-objs/mine', views.my_objs, name='my_objs'),
```

or use the same view, and pass `mine` to the view so that you can tell which URL pattern was matched.

```
url(r'latest-objs/mine', views.latest_objs, {'mine': True}, name='my_objs'),
```

If you go for the later approach, then you need to update the view to accept `mine` as an argument.

```
def latest_objs(request, mine=False):
    ...
```

Whether you reuse the same view or a different view is a matter of judgement, and in my opinion it depends on the views. For a simple view, a separate view would be most straight forward, since you can then use the login required decorator or mixins to handle the redirect. For a more complex view, a separate view might lead to duplicated code.